# Using Activator.CreateInstance to create instance of a class and inject Interface to constructor

Tags: c#, reflection

My goal is to create an instance of a class from it's AssemblyQualifiedName. The problem is that this class requires an interface to be passed in it's constructor and I am having trouble doing this with Activator.CreateInstance.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Once i have the AssemblyQualifiedName of the class I want to instantiate I got it's type using Type.GetType(AQN), used that type to find the constructor and get the required parameters.

I get stuck when calling Activator.CreateInstance and passing the parameters.

```cs
var objectType = Type.GetType(AQN);

var constructors = objectType.GetConstructors();

foreach (ConstructorInfo constructor in constructors)
{
    var parameters = constructor.GetParameters();                   
    var instantiatedObj = Activator.CreateInstance(objectType,parameters);
}
```

Once I do this i get the error "Constructor on Type xxx not found."

Comment: You are trying to use `parameters` in the wrong way. You need pass in instance of the parameter values there.

Comment: When you call `Activator.CreateInstance`, you need to pass the actual parameters to pass to the constructor. You're trying to pass an array of `ParameterInfo`, which describes the types of parameters that the constructor expects.

Comment: You're not passing the interface to the constructor. You're passing the reflection parameters!

Comment: Are you saying that you won't know what the constructor takes at design-time? You have to dynamically identify the interface and create an instance at run-time?

Comment: `constructor.GetParameters()` tells you *about* the parameters the constructor needs, like what types they are. It doesn't return the actual parameters, because only you know what they are. You might find it helpful to use an IoC/DI container because they manage a lot of this for you. They handle the reflection and they create instances of types.

Comment: How can i get the actual parameters from the ParameterInfo ?

Comment: I managed to get the System.Type of the interface i want to pass as a parameter, is there any way I can pass that to the constructor to initialize the class?

Comment: You need an implementation of the interface, you can't instantiate an interface directly. That is the difficult part of what you are trying to do. You might have no implementations referenced or you might have more than one. The fact that this is not straightforward is an indication of poor design. I suggest you back up and consider the "why" of what you are doing and try to come up with alternatives.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I think there must be an easier way to solve this. Going to have a look around and try again.

Answer (score 0):

There's a [Activator.CreateInstance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.activator.createinstance?view=netframework-4.8#System_Activator_CreateInstance_System_Type_System_Object___) that simply takes the type and the parameters to pass. So you can just say:

```
ISomeInterface something = null;

var objectType = Type.GetType(AQN);
var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(objectType, something);
```

Comment: I would like to do this but all the information i have about the Interface is this location.etc.etc.IEmailSender emailSender So I am looking for a way to use it somehow

Answer (score 0):

if you want to create an instance of the class dynamically then you can do it like this too

```
        Type type = Type.GetType(AQN);
        PropertyInfo[] properties = type.GetProperties();
        var instance = (BaseClass)Activator.CreateInstance(type);

        for (int i = 0; i < properties.Length; i++)
        {
            PropertyInfo propertyInfo = type.GetProperty(properties[i].Name);
            var propertyVal = Convert.ChangeType(yourpropertyvalue,  
                             properties[i].PropertyType);
            propertyInfo.SetValue(instance, propertyVal);
        }
        return instance;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! Going to try this and let you know

Comment: Ok so I'm trying to pass this IEmailsender Interface through the constructor here var instance = (BaseClass)Activator.CreateInstance(type); but I don't have the Interface all I have is it's location and it's name.

Comment: Is there any field of IEmailSender in your class whose instance you want to create?

Comment: The IEmailSender Interface requires a function called SendEmail(string recipient, string message);